# Why does Eclipse flag private methods with 'parameter is hiding a field', but not public methods?

Tags: java, eclipse

In this class:

```
class RuleSet {
  private final Collection<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<>();

  public void setRules(Collection<Rule> rules) {
    replaceRules(rules);
    // do something else here...
  }

  private void replaceRules(Collection<Rule> rules) {
    this.rules.clear();
    this.rules.addAll(rules);
  }
}
```

Eclipse (Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)) sets a warning on the private method that `the parameter rules is hiding a field from the type RuleSet`, but not on the public method that has the same parameter name.

Why is one a potential problem but not the other?

Comment: because you don't use both `rules` and `this.rules` within the public method?

Comment: it's worth mentioning which version you are currently using and whether other plugins of this kind are installed

Comment: my Eclipse doesn't have any warning with sonar plugin also

Comment: Added Eclipse version. I don't think any plugins are involved in this. And, @Andrew, changing the public method to use both `this.rules` and `rules` did not cause a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the warnings occur depends on your Eclipse -> Java settings (see image).

Set `Local variable declaration hides another field or variable` to warning to see the warnings from your example.

Or even set `Include constructor or setter method parameters` to get warnings if there is name shadowing in setters. This would show warnings in your setters and getters too.

[image]

Comment: Ah, it's not the `public` vs `private` that is making the difference. It's the fact that one of them has the magic word `set` in its name, and I don't have the `Include constructor or setter method parameters` option set. Thanks for pointing me down the right path,